# How can I get a well Structure CSS styled html profile?

Tags: html, css

I am looking to have a picture, name of the person, links to photos, biography, life, tell about you!  a map tag where the location will be shown, also at the right, there will be details like like, Born:  Nationality:  Ocupation, Trakcs:

Can any body help me with a semantic html structure style with CSS Please use http://jsfiddle.net/ to build it online Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Your Yard Sales onproducts.line</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="" type="text/css" media="screen" />

</head>
<style type="text/css" >
#space {

    margin-bottom:1.2em;

       }
ul {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 3em 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc; }
 li {
    float: left; }
 li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #069;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }
     </style>
<body> 
<ul>

<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Members</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Rollers</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
</ul>
 <br/>
  <br/>
   <br/>
    <br/>
<div id="space">
<a href="#">Roberto Kirt</a>



</div>
<!--<ul><li><a href="#">'.$name2.'</a></li>
<li><a href="#">'.$name2.'</a></li>
<li><a href="#">'.$name2.'</a></li></ul>-->

<table width="1768" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0.5">
  <tr>
    <td width="493" height="149"><img style="border:#666 1px solid;" src="images/profileimages/8.jpg" alt="Angel Pilier                   "align="left" width="100" height="130" border="1" /></td>
    <td width="1275"><table width="880" border="0.5" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
       <td width="145" height="31"> </td><td></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td height="44" align="right">Born:</td><td width="735">1975-11-23</td>

      </tr>
      <tr align="right">
        <td height="38"></td>
       >
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="36" align="right">Died:</td><td width="735">0000-00-00</td>

      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td height="31" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="31"><a href="#">Photos</a></td>
    <td rowspan="7"><table width="885" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="145" height="31" align="right"> Nationality:</td><td width="740"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr align="right">
    <td height="25">&nbsp;</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="24" align="right">Spouse:</td><td width="740"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="right">
    <td height="28">&nbsp;</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="27" align="right">Ocupation:</td><td width="740">Pianist</td>

  </tr>
  <tr align="right">
    <td height="27">&nbsp;</td>

  </tr>
   <td height="27" align="right">Childhood:</td><td width="740"></td>

  </tr>
     <tr align="right"><td height="27">&nbsp;</td>

  </tr>
     <td height="27" align="right">Tracks:</td><td width="740"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr align="right">
    <td height="119">&nbsp;</td>

  </tr>
</table>
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="25">  <a href="#">Biography</a></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="25"> <a href="#">Life</a></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="26"><a href="#">Tell an Anecdote</a></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>


  </tr>
  <tr>


  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><iframe width="700" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Rochester,+New York,+United States&amp;sspn=0.119541,0.110378&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Rochester,+New York,+United States&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed"></iframe></td>
   <!--<img src="images/foto.jpg" alt="nada" width="422" height="165" />-->
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How far have you gotten yourself? Post some of your attempts, and we can give you hints and help you out.

Comment: post your html and css, so that we can fix the issue

Comment: if you are good at html , divs , tables etc , you can easily do it.

Comment: This is not a place where you can ask for people to build stuff for you, you should come with specific, well explained questions, please take a look at our [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Yes, you should not be posting things for people to do them for you like @Trufa just said.. give it a try, post some code and then people will help.

Comment: P.S. there is not such thing as a map tag...

Comment: @joseeight I meant google map frame tags, in the profile, @Alan Yes I have posted the code above but it is a bunch of tables I want to convert to Div's, p, and other more semantics tags. I always have troulbe with that. @Kobe the html and CSS is as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@fello, there lot of things in your layout

1) use external stylesheet as much as possible because if you written your css in the head of html page it's make that html page heavy to load & you have to right new css in every new page.

2) try to avoid using table based structure as much as possible .Use div instead of table because it's flexible to use check [this](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/08/from-table-hell-to-div-hell/) for more.

3)didn't use `<br/>` to much .If you want to give spacing you can give with margin & padding .

4)ever browser have applied some there own default properties .So, avoid it you have to use [reset](http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-tips/css-tip-1-resetting-your-styles-with-css-reset/) sheet .

5)for semantic markup check these links :

a) http://www.html-and-css-tutorial.com/tutorial-3.html

b) http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/html5-page-structure/

c) http://themeshaper.com/2009/06/24/creating-wordpress-theme-html-structure-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

As far as I judge your question, use of some CSS framework like twitter-bootstrap will give you a very good and responsive layout in very less time :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use hcard. This and other microformats are described [here](http://microformats.org/).

Comment: fello, it is for semantic markup. You can read more on the website.